# Tankless gas water heater exhaust pipe

Tags: plumbing, water, pvc, heater, tankless

I installed a tankless gas water heater about 18 months ago. I used polypro for the exhaust pipe as I understand the MA code to require.

The polypropylene exhaust pipe extends something like 12 inches out from the house, and the exposed portion of the pipe has become extremely weathered looking. It is discolored and has small cracks along the top. The regular PVC pipe for air intake next to it looks perfect condition.

I am wondering if this degradation of the exhaust pipe is something to worry about, and if anyone else has experience with this material and its life expectancy. It seems like 18 months is a ridiculously short time period to see this type of weathering, especially on such a specialty expensive material.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: From a fast google search that is one of the worst plastics to be outside in the sun.  It probably has some UV blockers in it to last 18 months without shade.

Comment: My whole-house system uses PVC for both intake and exhaust, so you may want to recheck whether that's a genuine requirement or not.

Comment: @keshlam All flue gas vent must be accepted by the
MA Plumbing Board. MA Plumbing board
defines UL1738/ULCS636 listing as criteria
for flue gas vent material acceptance.

Comment: I think MTA's answer is spot on. If in doubt, ask your Local Authority Having Jurisdiction -- your town inspector -- what they would pass as acceptable.

Comment: Why is it necessary for the pipe to stick 12" out of the house? Mine are all fit with those horizontal termination kits, and they sit fairly flush to the house. Our code only requires that the exhaust is placed a certain distance from doors and windows.

Comment: When you replace the degraded section (or before installing it), I would paint the outside of the exposed section of pipe with a heat-resistant exterior paint. You should be able to get a color to your liking, or paint both the intake and exhaust vents so they color match.  That will protect it from sunlight exposure.

Answer (score 5):

[248 Mass. Reg. 5.12](https://casetext.com/regulation/code-of-massachusetts-regulations/department-248-cmr-board-of-state-examiners-of-plumbers-and-gas-fitters/title-248-cmr-500-amendments-to-nfpa-54/section-512-modifications-to-chapter-12-venting-of-appliances) says:

> Plastic Piping. The only plastic piping which may be used for venting
> appliances shall be CPVC, polypropylene, and other pipes which have
> been Product-accepted for that purpose by the Board.

So it's not true that *only* polypropylene is allowed. Your vent pipe could have been CPVC.

Comment: My reading of the above ("Product-accepted") is that the actual product sold, not just the material type, needs to be listed with the Plumbing Board.  OP may have used polypro not approved for this use.

Comment: @Armand It is a Centrotherm product approved for this use and is the only product sold for this use by the three plumbing supply houses I called in my area